# What is the relationship between random variable X and x

Tags: statistics, random-variables

When the sample size is 4, we get a random variable $\bar{X4}$ to represent the average. And also we get $\bar{x4}$ that has a value of 0.5. I’m wondering what’s the relationship between $\bar{X4}$ and $\bar{x4}$ ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "we get" $\overline{x4}$, but I suspect $\overline{x4}$ is a value of the random variable $\overline{X4}$.

Comment: What is $\bar x_4$?

Comment: My guess is that $\bar X_4$ stands for a random variable and that $\bar x_4$ stands for a numerical realization of that random variable. // Analogously, perhaps you have you have seen the notation $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4, p=.5)$ as the model for four tosses of a fair coin. Then after you actually toss such a coin four times, perhaps you observe $x = 3.$